# Differentiable function bounded between constant multiples

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

I honestly have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is f(x) non-zero? If so, you can divide through by f and integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split the inequality into two:

$f'\ge kf$, and $f'\leq Kf$, which are two inequality ODE's, now imagine we have the ODE:

$f'=Af\Rightarrow f(x)=f(0)e^{Ax}$, apply this to our two odes and we get:

$f(x)\leq f(0)e^{Kx}$ and $f(x)\ge f(0)e^{kx}$, merging these inequalities we get:

$f(0)e^{kx}\leq f(x)\leq f(0)e^{Kx}$ as desired.

Comment: thanks a lot! what a great answer